# How to unit test that a document has a given permission?

Tags: unit-testing, marklogic, marklogic-10

I'm setting up unit testing using marklogic-unit-test and one thing I'd like to do is check a given document has a particular permission. However, when I test my permission against a Sequence of permissions, I get an `XDMP-NONMIXEDCOMPLEXCONT` error. I assume this has to do with the fact that permissions are complex objects and not something like a simple string, because this works with collections.

```
const test = require("/test/test-helper.xqy");
let p1 = Sequence.from([xdmp.permission("rest-reader", "read", "element")]);
let p2 = Sequence.from([
  xdmp.permission("rest-reader", "read", "element"), 
  xdmp.permission("rest-writer", "update", "element")
]);
test.assertAtLeastOneEqual(p1, p2)
```

Which returns:

```
[javascript] XDMP-NONMIXEDCOMPLEXCONT: fn:data(<sec:permission 
xmlns:sec="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/security">
<sec:capability>...</sec:capability>...</sec:permission>) 
-- Node has complex type with non-mixed complex content
```

The best alternative I can come up with is to explicitly loop over the Sequence and do the comparison with `fn.deepEqual` on each element. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `test.assertAtLeastOneEqual()` function expects atomic values (`item()` signature). The only test helper function that can handle elements is `test.assertEqualXml()`, but that looks for exact matches. I think your best bet is to stringify the permissions. Something like this:

```
const test = require("/test/test-helper.xqy");
let p1 = [xdmp.permission("rest-reader", "read")];
let p2 = [
  xdmp.permission("rest-reader", "read"), 
  xdmp.permission("rest-writer", "update")
];
p1 = Sequence.from(p1.map(p => xdmp.roleName(p.roleId) + ':' + p.capability));
p2 = Sequence.from(p2.map(p => xdmp.roleName(p.roleId) + ':' + p.capability));
test.assertAtLeastOneEqual(p1, p2)
```